# Upgrade FreeBSD to specific patch version

Tags: freebsd, upgrade, patch

My FreeBSD is running version 11.2

```
FreeBSD host1 11.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 11.2-RELEASE #0 r335510: Fri Jun 22 04:32:14 UTC 2018     root@releng2.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

I wanted to upgrade to 11.2-RELEASE-p5 (due to specific reason)

I tried the following command, but failed.

```
root@host1:~ # freebsd-update -r 11.2-RELEASE-p5 upgrade
Looking up update.FreeBSD.org mirrors... 3 mirrors found.
Fetching metadata signature for 11.2-RELEASE from update4.freebsd.org... done.
Fetching metadata index... done.
Inspecting system... done.

The following components of FreeBSD seem to be installed:
kernel/generic kernel/generic-dbg src/src world/base world/base-dbg
world/doc world/lib32

The following components of FreeBSD do not seem to be installed:
world/lib32-dbg

Does this look reasonable (y/n)? y

Fetching metadata signature for 11.2-RELEASE-p5 from update4.freebsd.org... failed.
Fetching metadata signature for 11.2-RELEASE-p5 from update1.freebsd.org... failed.
Fetching metadata signature for 11.2-RELEASE-p5 from update2.freebsd.org... failed.
No mirrors remaining, giving up.
```

Now i am trying to upgrade via the source.  But i couldn't able to find the exact svn path to 11.2-RELEASE-p5

The documentation say to use

```
svnlite checkout https://svn.freebsd.org/base/releng/11.2 /usr/src
```

But this will fetch the latest code which is 11.2-RELEASE-p15 or something.

I wanted to upgrade my system to 11.2-RELEASE-p5 specifically.

Answer (score 0):

with [pkg(8)](https://manpage.me/?pkg) it's usually a matter of tracking the release you're on: releng (12-CURRENT) , or stable (12-STABLE) for example. In both of those cases, you're getting whatever the latest **revision** that is available for the **[release](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/)** you're tracking. I highlighted `revision` as given FreeBSD is tracked with [svn(1)](https://manpage.me/?svn). Every time you checkout, or "upgrade". You're generally `up`ing to the latest `revision` available at the time. In `svn`(lite) parlance. That's `svn up svn://svn.freebsd.org/base/stable /usr/src` for the latest `revision` of FreeBSD `source` for the (current) **stable** branch. A *particular* stable branch would be `svn up svn://svn.freebsd.org/base/stable/9 /usr/src` for 9-STABLE. For a specific *revision* of 11-STABLE. You would check it out thusly `svn up -r 123456 svn://svn.freebsd.org/base/stable/11 /usr/src`. Which would give you `revision 123456` in the 11-STABLE branch. Finding the *branch* you're interested in, might be as easy as browsing [svn.freebsd.org](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/), and finding the `revision` you're interested in, on the branch you're tracking. Or even getting/tracking a *newer* branch. See also: [freebsd-update](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?freebsd-update)